# Flutter - Catch error if rest api not load data and device is not on internet

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my API

```
Future<void> getItems(int id) async {
    final uri = Uri.parse('$kApiUrl${kApiUrlItems}P_ID=$id');
    http.Response response = await http.get(uri).timeout(kTimeoutDuration); //5 sec

    try {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        //ok
      }
      else {
        await Fluttertoast.showToast(...);
      }
    }
    on SocketException catch (e) {
        await Fluttertoast.showToast(...);
    } on TimeoutException catch (e) {
        await Fluttertoast.showToast(...);
    } catch (e) {
        await Fluttertoast.showToast(...);
    }
  }
```

When disable WIFI and Mobile data on emulator got error in console eg. **Unhandled Exception: Failed host lookup:**

Is it possible catch this error and show in  Fluttertoast or snackbar?

I'm added  SocketException, TimeoutException and catch but don't get error within them!

Comment: Yes this is possible . You just pass 'e.response' inside showtoast method

Comment: @Noyon  I'm try but Not show in toast error in conslole only!

Comment: I try this by using getx with dio, in get snackbar(). where i add await before snackbar.  await get.snackbar(e.response.data) inside catch block

Answer (score 2):

You can try wrap final uri and  response  in **try** like this:

```
Future<void> getItems(int id) async {
    try {
      final uri = Uri.parse('$kApiUrl${kApiUrlItems}P_ID=$id');
      http.Response response = await http.get(uri).timeout(kTimeoutDuration); //5 sec
    
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        //ok
      }
      else {
        await Fluttertoast.showToast(...);
      }
    }
    on SocketException catch (e) {
        await Fluttertoast.showToast(...);
    } on TimeoutException catch (e) {
        await Fluttertoast.showToast(...);
    } catch (e) {
        await Fluttertoast.showToast(...);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to check the internet connection first before sending the API You can check it using this https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus
after installing this update your project like this

```
Future<bool> checkInternetConnection() async {
  var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
  if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

Future<void> getItems(int id) async {
if(checkInternetConnection()){
    try {
      final uri = Uri.parse('$kApiUrl${kApiUrlItems}P_ID=$id');
      http.Response response = await http.get(uri).timeout(kTimeoutDuration); //5 sec
    
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        //ok
      }
      else {
        await Fluttertoast.showToast(...);
      }
    }
    on SocketException catch (e) {
        await Fluttertoast.showToast(...);
    } on TimeoutException catch (e) {
        await Fluttertoast.showToast(...);
    } catch (e) {
        await Fluttertoast.showToast(...);
    }}else{
//show toast to turn on wifi or data
    }
      }
```